# textViewDidChange is only changing when a full string is typed. I want it to check every character

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have a UITextView that dynamically changes in height when text is typed beyond it's frame's bounds. However, the height will only change once the full string is typed and you press space. This leaves an awkward moment where the user can't see the word they're typing.

How can I have my `textViewDidChange` react for every character typed rather than when a full string is entered?

This is the initialized variable:

```
lazy var descriptionTextView: UITextView = {
    let tv = UITextView()
    tv.backgroundColor = .white
    tv.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
    tv.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 40)
    tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tv.delegate = self
    tv.isScrollEnabled = false
    return tv
}()
```

Then I add it to the subview and anchor it in my `viewDidLoad`:

```
view.addSubview(descriptionTextView)

descriptionTextView.anchor(top: privacyLabel.bottomAnchor, left: 
view.leftAnchor, bottom: descriptionTextViewUnderLine.topAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 16, paddingLeft: 24, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 24, width: 0, height: 40)
```

In an extension, I put `textViewDidChange`

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    let size = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: .infinity)
    let estimatedSize = textView.sizeThatFits(size)
    textView.constraints.forEach { (constraint) in
        if constraint.firstAttribute == .height {
            constraint.constant = estimatedSize.height
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but may go towards the spirit of what you're trying to do.  If you disable scrolling on your textView, its intrinsic size becomes the size of its text, ie, you don't have to set a height constraint to it to have it show all of its text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`textViewDidChange(...)` actually should react for every character entered (via keyboard, not programmatically).  It's possible that `textView.sizeThatFits(...)` doesn't return what you want.  A quick look at the documentation doesn't reveal an override to UIView's implementation, which just returns the same size of of the view.

NSAttributedString's [boundingRect(with:options:context:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/1529154-boundingrect) might be worth looking into to get back the desired size of the text (and thus of the view).

Also note my comment to your question.  Setting `scrollEnabled` to false should already set the intrinsic size of the textView to the size that you need, and you shouldn't even have to set a height constraint.  If your textView is getting squashed between views with constraints of equal priority, you can raise the `compressionResistancePriority` along the vertical axis.

A quick snippet to illustrate the example (not an answer to your question, but maybe a different approach to what you're trying to do):

```
//: A UIKit based Playground for presenting user interface

import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
    private lazy var textView = UITextView()
    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .orange


        textView.frame = view.bounds
        textView.backgroundColor = .white
        textView.isScrollEnabled = false
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(textView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(
            [textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor)]
        )

        textView.delegate = self
        self.view = view
    }

    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        print(textView.text)
    }
}
// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

Comment: The keyboard in a playground is painful to work with, but you'll see that when you type enough text to reach a second line, the textView will increase in height to accommodate both lines.  Note the delegate doesn't play a part in the height change.  I'm just using it to illustrate that it does respond to each character changed via keyboard input.

Comment: You were right!! Since I had the `.isScrollEnabled` set to false, I just changed the height in my anchor to zero (and i took away the `tv.frame = CGRect` portion because that was redundant). Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Glad to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented this using constraints in storyboard.

The storyboard is like below:
[image]

Code that I have added in Controller is :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var messageTextView: UITextView!

    @IBOutlet weak var messageTextViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
}

extension ViewController: UITextViewDelegate {

    public func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        resizeTextView(textView: textView)
    }

    func resizeTextView(textView: UITextView) {
        let sizeThatFitsTextView = messageTextView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: messageTextView.frame.width, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)))

        messageTextViewHeightConstraint.constant = sizeThatFitsTextView.height
    }

}
```

I am changing the height of the `UITextView` dynamically using constraints here and it increases if you will add text beyond it's frame.

Hope this helps to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `UITextView` frame instead of `UIView`.

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    let size = CGSize(width: textView.frame.width, height: .infinity)
    let estimatedSize = textView.sizeThatFits(size)
    textView.constraints.forEach { (constraint) in
        if constraint.firstAttribute == .height {
            constraint.constant = estimatedSize.height
        }
    }
}
```